# Get path of JSON value using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to find a path of a JSON value. Consider the following JSON:

```
{
    "car": {
        "type": [{
            "sedan": {
                "make": "honda",
                "model": "civics"
            }
        },
        {
            "coupe": {
                "make": "ford",
                "model": "escort"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

How can I get the path of the value "honda"? I'm looking to find something like this...

car_type_0_sedan_make_**honda**

Does JSON.NET support this? I see that there is a **JToken.Path** property but it is currently not available. http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/24136

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Update to the [latest version](https://json.codeplex.com/releases) of Json.NET.  The `Path` property was added to `JToken` in [version 5.0 release 1](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/104679) (April 7, 2013).

Here is a test program you can use to verify that it works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""car"": {
                ""type"": [{
                    ""sedan"": {
                        ""make"": ""honda"",
                        ""model"": ""civics""
                    }
                },
                {
                    ""coupe"": {
                        ""make"": ""ford"",
                        ""model"": ""escort""
                    }
                }]
            }
        }";

        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken token = obj["car"]["type"][0]["sedan"]["make"];
        Console.WriteLine(token.Path + " -> " + token.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
car.type[0].sedan.make -> honda
```

Comment: I just installed the dll from NuGet but Visual Studio properties says Version 4.5.0.0. But looking in ~/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.8/Lib/net45, the properties on the file says version 5.0.8.16617. Anyway, I get this error [Method not found: 'System.String Newtonsoft.Json.LinqJToken.get_Path()'.]

Comment: It works for me.  I added a test program to my answer that I used to test it.  Is your project somehow referencing an older version of Json.Net?  Do you have an old version installed in your GAC?  If you run the above code in a new project, does that work?  The version numbers you cited look correct-- the latest version has a DLL version of 5.0.8.16617 and an assembly version of 4.5.0.0.

Comment: I just tried this again on another computer and it works! I think you're right, my first computer must be referencing an old version somehow. I'll dig into that issue later but thank you so much!

Answer (score 31):

You could also try the `SelectToken` method like this:

```
var j = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = j.SelectToken("car.type[0].sedan.make");
Console.WriteLine(token.Path + " -> " + token.ToString());
```

Outputs:

```
car.type[0].sedan.make -> honda
```

Comment: I was looking for something like SelectToken because I thought an excellent library such as NewtonSoft.Json would have a nice feature like this :)

Answer (score 5):

There is also a way to retrieve the path just by the value, using linq. You will need Json.NET for this.

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = jo.Descendants()
                    .OfType<JProperty>()
                    .Where(p => p.Value.ToString() == "honda")
                    .First();

        Console.WriteLine(token.Path);
```

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vZ1zLg

Answer (score -4):

you can Convert the Json to dynamic object as below.

```
JavaScriptSerializer js=new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dataObject=Json.Decode(jsonString);
```

Then you can reflect over it and find out your string "honda" and construct the path as you like.

Comment: How would you search for value within the dataObject you have above?

Comment: var is not dynamic. Its type is inferred in compile-time.