# Using JPath, how do I return a value based on another key value pair of the same node?

Tags: json, json.net

I have the following JSON file. It is truncated for brevity of this question. An actual JSON file would contain 10 - 20 messages and 3 - 15 results.

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "type": "msgInfo",
            "description": "Some stuff happened"
        },
        {
            "type": "msgInfo",
            "description": "More stuff happened"
        },
        {
            "type": "msgInfo",
            "description": "yup, more stuff happened"
        }
    ],
    "results": [
        {
            "parameterId": "val_1",
            "dataType": "Double",
            "value": 123.45
        },
        {
            "parameterId": "val_2",
            "dataType": "Double",
            "value": 246.80
        },
        {
            "parameterId": "val_3",
            "dataType": "Double",
            "value": 135.79
        },
        {
            "parameterId": "val_4",
            "dataType": "Long",
            "value": 20161021
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value of the `value` key based on the value of the  `parameterId` key. For example, I need to return "123.45" using a JPath to "val_1".

So far I have this code (copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892617/get-path-of-json-value-using-json-net#) post) but I can't get the path correct.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken token = obj["results"]["parameterId"];

Console.WriteLine(token.Path + " -> " + token.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

What do I need to do in order to return "123.45" using a JPath to "val_1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `value` token from one of the results in the `results` array based on the value of the `parameterId` token, you need to use the [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method with a [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query expression:

```
JToken token = obj.SelectToken("$.results[?(@.parameterId=='val_1')].value");
```

JSONPath syntax can be a little tricky to get right sometimes, depending on what you're trying to do, so you might find an online expression evaluator such as [this one](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) helpful to experiment with.

Alternatively, you can use a LINQ query to do the same thing:

```
JToken token = obj["results"]
    .Where(result => (string)result["parameterId"] == "val_1")
    .Select(result => result["value"])
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is a fiddle showing both approaches: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8qiSCa